# Angularjs route doesn't load login.html into main.html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

While i am trying to do a single page application using angular.I am unable to load login.html view into ng-view of main.html.Kindly some one help me to do that.thanks in advance.

main.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="assets/images/favicon.ico"      />
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container-fluid page-header"
    style="background-color: #E7E7D2; margin: 0; border-bottom-color: green;">
    <h2>
        Application <small>Heading</small>
    </h2>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="main">

    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    <div data-ng-view></div>

</div>
<script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<div data-ng-app="loginApp" class="row"
data-ng-controller="loginController">
<div class="col-md-offset-4"
    style="background-color: #E7E7D2; height: 200px; width: 400px;">
    <h3 align="center">Login</h3>
    <p align="center">{{login_error}}</p>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-md-12"
                style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" data-ng-model="userName"
                    placeholder="Email" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12"
                style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px">
                <input type="password" class="form-control"
                    data-ng-model="password" placeholder="password" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

app.module.js

```
 var app = angular.module('loginApp',[
 'ngRoute',
 ]);
```

app.routes.js

```
    angular.module('loginApp').config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    templateUrl : 'components/login/login.html',
    controller : 'loginController'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: 'components/login/login.html'
});
```

}]);

loginController.js

```
 angular.module('loginApp').controller('loginController', function($scope) {
function loginController() {
    alert("hi");
} 
});
```

Folder structure

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm a novice in Angular, and I don't have time to try it now, but I'm start learning angular and I've noticed that you missed ng-app call in main.html.
Maybe I'm wrong and it's not important. So sorry in that case.

Comment: <script src="app/app.module.js"></script> that line i call that

Comment: I mean <body ng-app="myApp">

Comment: ok i get it let me try that

Comment: yes ,you are right.kindly send some links to learn indepth.

Comment: Happy to be helpful. I'm learning the fundament here :)  https://www.codecademy.com/learn  If my comment was useful for the discussion put a flag.

Comment: @Gianca now i am getting "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined".kindly help me to find out my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared ng-app in the child window instead of the parent window.
angular wont render main.html(angular scope starts with ng-app) so ng-view will do nothing.
you need to put this attribute on the body or another wrapping tag

Comment: I want to learn angularjs in depth.kindly give some links.now i am getting "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined".kindly help me to find out my mistake

Comment: your controller doesn't look right. maybe you should start with some tutorial before you dive in? check this: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/

Comment: angular.module('loginApp').controller('loginController', function($scope) {
    alert("hi");
});

Answer (score 0):

Ya, What @Avi said is correct. Declare ng-app in body or in html tag. It will work!!.

Comment: that i am fixing, now i am getting "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined".kindly help me to find out my mistake